# C bufferoverflow prevention, safe upper bound check in multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, nullreferenceexception, buffer-overflow, isnull

Consider this piece of C code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char ***map = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 4);
        char *a[] = { "hello", "world" };
        char *b[] = { "foo", "bar" };
        char *c[] = { "test", "last" };
        map[0] = a;
        map[1] = b;
        map[2] = c;

        char *p = NULL;
        int offset = 30; // buffer exploited!

        p = **map + offset;
        if (!p)
                puts("err"); // not detected?
        else
                printf("%p %s\n", p, p);

        return 0;
}
```

How to get (eficiently and safely) upper bounding address of map, to avoid bufferoverflow errors, because if I access `char **p = map[random_offset];` directly eventually will cause runtime error

Comment: Are you a triple star programmer by chance? Also, your definition of `map` appears to be wrong. You are allocating four pointers to `char`, so your declaration ought to be `char **map`.

Comment: @FUZxxl You are wrong. His declaration is correct as he wants to point to arrays of `char *` (who are `char **` then).

Comment: @junix: Then his `malloc` is wrong. He clearly allocated an array of four `char*`.

Comment: @FUZxxl Wrong again. He allocated an array of 4 pointers. Nothing more will he need.

Comment: @junix But then it is only char `**map` and not char `***map`. He should change the malloc statement to `malloc(sizeof(char**)*4)`.

Comment: @FUZxxl There is no difference between the results of the statements `sizeof(char **)` and `sizeof(char *)`.

Comment: @junix The C standard indeed requires the results of `sizeof(char**)` to be equal to the result of `sizeof(char*)` but it is extremely confusing if you use an expression inside the `sizeof` that does not represent what is actually being stored. IMHO the best statement is `malloc(4*sizeof*map)` as it can never be wrong  as long as the number of elements is right and it avoids repeating the type's name.

Comment: @FUZxxl not really, I just wanna make it this way here :)

Comment: Obligatory link to [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: @junix The C standard allows `sizeof(char**) != sizeof(char*)`. You're guaranteed that `[(un)signed] char*` and `void*` have the same representation and alignment requirements; pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements; and all pointers to `struct`s resp. `union`s too. "Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements." (6.2.5, 28) In practice, you'll have a hard time finding an implementation where `char*` and `char**` have different sizes, but it's allowed.

Answer (score 3):

By default there is no detection of out of bounds access. You have to handle it yourself.

Your assumption that out of bounds pointers have null value is wrong and the following the condition is incorrect.

```
 if (!p)
            puts("err"); // not detected?
```

Accessing random memory loations using pointer arithmatic is *allowed* in C but not valid.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that memory is not by default initialized with NULL

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep track of the address you are accessing yourself. This can be eased by using access through array indices rather than using pointer arithmetic. (e.g. `map[entryID][0]` for key or `map[entryID][1]` for value). This makes it easy to check if entryID exceeds the maximum index. 0-1 are by contract always valid.

**Update:** 
If you want to keep track of the array statistics (such as maximum length, number of valid entries, ...) you have to take care of it yourself. You could achieve this by embedding your map pointer into a struct together with the needed statistic fields:

```
typedef struct MyMap {
    char ***map;
    unsigned int capacity;
    unsigned int last_index;
}tMyMap;

//...

void useTheMap(tMyMap *map);

// ...

    tMyMap mapInstance;

    mapInstance.map = malloc(...);
    mapInstance.capacity = ...;
    mapInstance.last_index = ...;

    useTheMap(&mapInstance);

    // ...

    for (int i = 0;i < mapInstance.last_index;i++) {
        //...
    }
```

Of course you have to take care of updating the statistic fields yourself. But this would give you the oportunity to find out the capacity of the map at runtime at cost of the overhead for updating the statistic fields... (It's actually the way how e.g. other - more convenient - string implementations in other languages work)

Comment: Sorry, don't understand this question. I didn't write anything about crashes.

Comment: No, I got you point, you are proposing to make map static array, then it wouldn't be an issue, but my aim was to calculate array bounds in __runtime__

Comment: @user2013697 Getting runtime bounds information is a job left to the programmer in C. I updated an idea how you could build a system giving you that opportunity. The creators of C left this out in order to not pollute the memory with unneeded information but I understand why it's sometimes desirable to have such functionality.  In these cases you need to provide it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have allocated space for a sentinel in the map, but not assigned it a value. Either, use something like `memset(...)` or `map [3] = (char **) 0;` to force the terminator.

Then, you can track the length of the map, or scan linearly from the beginning until reaching a match or the terminator before stopping. Junix response provides for the first alternative. If the list is not ordered, then a linear search is necessary in any event and the length will not really help.

The observation about the error in the type in `malloc(...)` is correct - the language, however, is not able to verify the type against the LHS value in C. Fortunately `char *` and `char **` are both pointer types, and have the same size.